# Linksys WRT150n: how to migrate from Sveasoft to DD-WRT?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, 802.11n

Since I started using multiple laptops with 802.11n, my WRT150n periodically loses wireless capability and I have bounce the box to regain wireless.  Before getting a new router, I wanted to try different firmware to see whether that would resolve the issue.

I don't want to brick my router, so is it possible to migrate from Sveasoft Talisman/Basic V1.3.1 to DD-WRT?

If so, which version of DD-WRT should I use?  I checked my router and the following options are listed for my router:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way not to brick your router is to revert your firmware back to the original stock Linksys firmware if possible.  Then, when flashing dd-wrt on it, follow the directions exactly, and do the 30-30-30 reset properly.

If you have a 4MB router, which it's saying you do, then you have enough room for the bigger images which have more features.  Sounds like you probably want to do the `dd-wrt.v24_std_generic.bin` image.